# Port specific RMI application

Tags: rmi

Question :
How do I make my RMI application to be IP and Port specific ?
    It means I want that when my application initializes then it'll ask for port and root systems IP address and a port where application could execute independently

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the part where you ask the user for the data, in an RMI client this is just a matter of building the lookup string for `Naming.lookup()` dynamically instead of statically: e.g. instead of

```
MyRemote mr = (MyRemote)Naming.lookup("rmi://somehost:someport/MyRemote")
```

you would have

```
String host; // initialized by dialogue with user
int port;    // initialized by dialogue with user
MyRemote mr = (MyRemote)Naming.lookup("rmi://"+host+":"+port+"/MyRemote")
```

At the RMI server end, the port number is provided to `super()` when constructing your remote object, if you extend `UnicastRemoteObject`, otherwise to `UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject()` if you don't extend  `UnicastRemoteObject`. Normally you don't need to specify your own host at all; an exception is if you are behind a NAT device or some other form of port-forwarding firewall, in which case you need to specify the host in the `java.rmi.server.hostname` property in the server JVM, before you export any remote objects (including the Registry).